# Showing that the primary component $G_p$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

For a finite abelian group $G$ and a prime number $p$ with $p \mid |G|$, we define $G_p$ as the subset of $G$ that contains all elements of $G$ with order $p^k$ for a $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$. We call $G_p$ the $p$-primary component of $G$.

I now want to show that $G_p$ is a subgroup of $G$.

We have that $G_p ≠ \emptyset$, because $ord(e_G) = p^0 = 1$. I also already know that for any $g \in G_p$, $g^{-1} \in G_p$ (because the inverse has the same order for each element of the group, which I have already shown).

The only thing I'm still struggling with is showing that for $g, h \in G_p$, $g h \in G_p$. I can see that if $ord(g) = p^k, ord(h) = p^l$, then $ord(g h) ≤ p^{k + l}$. However, I've been sitting here for several minutes and just couldn't figure out why $ord(gh)$ is of the shape $p^m$ for any $m \in \mathbb{N}_0$ itself. (For all I know, it could be that $ord(g h) = q^m$ for some $q \mid |G|, q ≠ p$, since $|G|$ can have more than one prime factor.) There is probably a simple argument I'm missing for why that's the case, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying that the order of $g$ is $p^k$ for some $k$ is the same as saying that $g^{p^m}=1$ for some $m$.

One direction is clear, the other one follows from the fact that if $r>0$ and $g^r=1$, then the order of $g$ is a divisor of $r$.

Now, suppose $g$ and $h$ belong to the primary component; then $g^{p^m}=1$ and $h^{p^n}=1$ for some $m$ and $n$. Then notice that
$$
(gh)^{p^{m+n}}=1
$$
and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

It's because $G$ is **abelian** so $(gh)^e = g^e h^e.$

This isn't true for example when $G = S_3$ and you look at the elements of order $1$ and $2$.

Comment: I don't think that alone is sufficient, though. Because $e_G = g^m h^n = (g^m)^n (h^n)^m = (g h)^{m n}$, whe have that $ord(gh) ≤ ord(g) ord(h)$. But unless I'm missing something, I can't use that argument alone to show that $ord(gh) = p^k$ for a $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$, can I?